# RNFirebaseMessaging in AppDelegate.o Symbol not found

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

Environment:

Target Platform:
iOS (iOS 11.3 - iPhone 8)
Development Operating System:
macOS Sierra
Build tools: Xcode
"react-native": "0.53.3",
"react-native-firebase": "^3.3.1",

I already done and redone react-native link react-native-firebase and unlink.
I deleted the derived data folder several times.
clean, and restart xcode several times.
I also uninstall react-native-firebase.

Note :

when I import

## import "RNFirebaseMessaging.h"

I have no problem.
it is when I use the following functions that build failed :

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
  [RNFirebaseMessaging didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(nonnull NSDictionary *)userInfo {
  [RNFirebaseMessaging didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo];
}
```

[image]